# How to use itertools for getting unique row items using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
ID,Region,Supplier,year,output
1,ANZ,AB,2021,1
2,ANZ,ABC,2022,1
3,ANZ,ABC,2022,1
4,ANZ,ABE,2021,0
5,ANZ,ABE,2021,1
6,ANZ,ABQ,2021,1
7,ANZ,ABW,2021,1
8,AUS,ABO,2020,1
9,KOREA,ABR,2019,0
```

I am trying to generate unique combination of `region` and `supplier` values. Instead of a groupby, I was thinking to do via `zip_longest`.

So, I tried the below

```
for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(region_values,supplier_values,fillvalue="ANZ"):
    print(i,j)
```

But the above results in incorrect entries for `i and j`.

I want to get each unique combination from a specific row. I don't wish to multiply/generate  new combinations which is not there in the data

**Currently, this results in incorrect output** as shown below

```
ANZ AB
AUS ABC  #incorrect to generating new combinations like this
KOREA ABE #incorrect to generating new combinations like this
ANZ ABQ
ANZ ABW
ANZ ABO
ANZ ABR
```

**I expect my output to be like as shown below**

```
ANZ AB
ANZ ABC
ANZ ABE
ANZ ABQ
ANZ ABW
AUS ABO
KOREA ABR
```

I use zip_longest because after this, I want to use the output from zip object to filter dataframe using 2 columns

Comment: I think you need `for i,j in itertools.product(region_values,supplier_values):` ?

Comment: but product also generates incorrect non-existent combination for other regions like aus and korea. see updated post screenshot

Comment: I basically want to iterate each unique combination of region and supplier. If not zip_longest and product, what would be the right method to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ordering is important need remove duplicates by both columns together, so instead `unique` need `drop_duplicates`:

```
column_name = "Region"
col_name = "Supplier"
df = data.drop_duplicates([column_name, col_name])    
        
for i,j in zip(df[column_name],df[col_name]):
    print(i,j)
    ANZ AB
    ANZ ABC
    ANZ ABE
    ANZ ABQ
    ANZ ABW
    AUS ABO
    KOREA ABR
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a set:

```
set(zip(df['Region'], df['Supplier']))
```

output:

```
{('ANZ', 'AB'),
 ('ANZ', 'ABC'),
 ('ANZ', 'ABE'),
 ('ANZ', 'ABQ'),
 ('ANZ', 'ABW'),
 ('AUS', 'ABO'),
 ('KOREA', 'ABR')}
```

For iteration:

```
for r, s in set(zip(df['Region'], df['Supplier'])):
    pass
```

if order is important use `dict.from_keys`:

```
for a,b in dict.fromkeys(zip(df['Region'], df['Supplier'])).keys():
    print(a,b)
```

Comment: @TheGreat if order is important, see update

Comment: btw, what do you mean by order? because your previous output is alreaady in order as in input dataframe? How does ordering the outout help? just trying to understand when can it be hlpful?

Comment: order is not guaranteed with sets ;)